# App throws OutOfMemoryExceptions on a tablet computer but enough memory left

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, out-of-memory, tablet

i've written a WPF application. It runs good on every pc and my test tablet pc, too.

Only on one tablet computer from a customer it throws OutOfMemoryExeptions after the main form has loaded. Some icons are visible on my form, some that are loaded later in the startup procedure are not visible. Those images are not big or something (just 200 kb each). The task manager says that there is only 800 MB used (it has 2 GB Memory). So there is enough Memory...

Interesting is that the application runs if my customer uninstalls the intel graphic driver, but that would be not a good solution.

Specs of the tablet:
It is a Kupa X11 with 2 GB Memory, Intel GMA 600 graphics and Windows 7 Professional.

Anyone an idea what it can be?

Thank you,
Daniel

Answer (score 1):

.NET applications are limited to the amount of memory they can use

> the .NET runtime will allow your app to use up to approx 3GB of address space.  However, depending on how you're allocating, there may not be a contiguous block of memory large enough to satisfy your allocation.  Also, .NET imposes a 2GB object size limit, so trying to allocate an array larger than 2GB will fail
>    - [msdn question](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/clr/thread/c50ea343-b41b-467d-a457-c5a735e4dfff/)

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me that if the application runs after uninstalling the current graphics driver, that it is a problem with the driver, and the OutOfMemoryException could be video memory.

Check with Intel for an updated driver or use the default video for Windows 7 (if that's an option).

Another thing you could try is updating DirectX on the machine.